# How to increase the number of iterations to optimize my cost function at each step using partial_fit at Scikit SGDClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, online-machine-learning

When using partial_fit at Scikit SGDClassifier the number of iteration for the convergence of the cost functions equals 1, as stated in the description:

> Perform one epoch of stochastic gradient descent on given samples.
> Internally, this method uses max_iter = 1. Therefore, it is not guaranteed that a minimum of the cost function is reached after calling it once. Matters such as objective convergence and early stopping should be handled by the user.

How can I increase max_iter such that my cost function is optimized properly and not just with one iteration? Or related to the scikit- description, how can I handle “objective convergence” and “early stopping” to my classifier using partial_fit?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply execute the `partial_fit()` command repeatedly with the same data, e.g. with the same batch. Here is my code fragment, where I just programmed a loop around the `partial_fit()` command:

```
for i_iter in np.arange(iter_per_batch):
       clf.partial_fit(X_batch, y_batch, classes=[0,1])
```

The variable `iter_per_batch` defines the number of iterations.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the `fit()` method instead of the `partial_fit()` method and increase the `max_iter` by providing an integer value for the number of iterations you would like to have for the SGDClassifier. The default here is 1000 iterations.

Have a look at the documentation with the max_iter parameter: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html

Comment: I need partial_fit(), because I am using it as an online learner, which requires that after each step the weights are updated based on the actual weight values. I think, that when I use fit() these weights are not updated based on the actual weight values. I think they are initialized.

Comment: Hm, maybe I misunderstood it. Why don't you just try to build a loop around the partial_fit method? I think that should work too.