# Python Sklearn MLPClassifier: Iteration while using partial_fit()

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

How can I get iteration in sklearn MLPClassifier while using `partial_fit()`?

I tried using `partial_fit` again and again on same batch of data, but Every time sklearn counts it as a new thing. Here is the part of my code:

```
for batch_start in range(0, X.shape[0], batch_size):
    iterationss=iterationss+1
    batch_end = min(batch_start + batch_size, X.shape[0])
    batch_X = X[batch_start:batch_end]
    batch_y = responses[batch_start:batch_end]
    for iii in range(max_iter):
        clf.partial_fit(batch_X, batch_y,classes=np.unique(responses))
    joblib.dump(clf,"clf_chatbot.pkl")
    print("Fitted till %d and saved."%(iterations*batch_size))
```

But output was like: (on windows 10 64 bit, python 3.10 amd 64)

```
Iteration 1, loss = 11.39555463
Iteration 1, loss = 11.35046939
Iteration 1, loss = 11.28887876
Iteration 1, loss = 11.18390311
Iteration 1, loss = 10.98991956
Iteration 1, loss = 10.64000362
Iteration 1, loss = 10.04894330
Iteration 1, loss = 9.14103649
Iteration 1, loss = 8.02487529
Iteration 1, loss = 7.25677016
Iteration 1, loss = 7.02518236
Iteration 1, loss = 6.98103370
Iteration 1, loss = 6.98184770
Iteration 1, loss = 7.00211247
Iteration 1, loss = 7.03137822
Iteration 1, loss = 7.05796926
Iteration 1, loss = 7.07287387
Iteration 1, loss = 7.07502399
Iteration 1, loss = 7.06933910
Iteration 1, loss = 7.06131838
Iteration 1, loss = 7.05424598
Iteration 1, loss = 7.04926004
Iteration 1, loss = 7.04628450
Training loss did not improve more than tol=0.000100 for 10 consecutive epochs. Stopping.
Iteration 1, loss = 7.04474045
Training loss did not improve more than tol=0.000100 for 10 consecutive epochs. Stopping.
Iteration 1, loss = 7.04394393
Training loss did not improve more than tol=0.000100 for 10 consecutive epochs. Stopping.
Iteration 1, loss = 7.04331604
Training loss did not improve more than tol=0.000100 for 10 consecutive epochs. Stopping.
Iteration 1, loss = 7.04245835
Training loss did not improve more than tol=0.000100 for 10 consecutive epochs. Stopping.
Iteration 1, loss = 7.04114971
Training loss did not improve more than tol=0.000100 for 10 consecutive epochs. Stopping.
Iteration 1, loss = 7.03933200
```

Expected Output: (Which i am getting, but only on my android run using "pydroid3" app. exact files and code and all)

```
Iteration 1,..
Iteration 2,..
...
```

Why is my iteration always counting as first iteration on windows? How can I fix it?

Please notice that this question is not a duplicate of [How to increase the number of iterations to optimize my cost function at each step using partial_fit at Scikit SGDClassifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63722729/4685471) . My problem is not solved with the solution proposed there.